# NHibernate mapping change delete command for object

Tags: sql, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Hi I would like to know how i can change manually change the default sql command to delete an object in the nhibernate mapping file.
I want to use sevral delete commands at the same time, all using the id, how will I go about that?

Comment: Have you considered using cascading deletes? Or, are you trying to delete from tables that are not mapped by NH?

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-cud

> Hibernate3 can use custom SQL statements for create, update, and delete operations. The class and collection persisters in Hibernate already contain a set of configuration time generated strings (insertsql, deletesql, updatesql etc.). The mapping tags <sql-insert>, <sql-delete>, and <sql-update> override these strings:

```
<class name="Person">
    <id name="id">
        <generator class="increment"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name" not-null="true"/>
    <sql-delete>DELETE FROM PERSON WHERE ID=?</sql-delete>
</class>
```

Comment: What does the '?' stand for, is it always the id? does it go by the order of properties... I want to use sevral delete commands at the same time, all using the id, how will I go about that.

Comment: Sorry, you've exposed the (short) limit of my NHibernate knowledge :) Perhaps someone can scoop this answer by adding that explanation.

Comment: `?` is the parameter placeholder. I believe the first one would always be the object's id property for the sql-delete element.

Comment: A single object deleting several rows seems odd to me, if not wrong.  It seems like you'd want to map items for each table, and make your delete cascade, instead.  If you really want to add multiple deletes, you could probably just put semi-colons between SQL statements.

Comment: This may also be a good case for stored procedures, which you can call from NHibernate if you jump through some hoops (like this `sql-delete` in your mapping).

Comment: The thing is I have many unmapped tables that I wat to delete references to the object I'm deleting from. Unfotounaltly, I just realized that I'm not using nhibernate 3 but 2.2 I can't really chage that right now... anyway I decided to simply hard code the necesery command in code, thanks for the help anyway...

Comment: @HeWhoSleepPrograms: For what little help I had to offer, you're welcome.  If you stumble across a better solution later, I'd suggest you post it as an answer.